# what preposition goes with "After"

Tags: prepositions

Let's say there's a couple; the husband died and after 2 years the wife married someone else.

We can say:

> She got married 2 years after his death.

Can we also say:

> After his death **by** 2 years she got married?

I'm asking about the right preposition to use in this case; if it's not "by" then what is it?

Some more examples:
After I had finished my meal **by** 10 minutes I felt hungry.
After I was born **by** 10 minutes my mom died.

Comment: No ***by*** is not correct. There is no alternative- That construction is just not valid.  You must rephrase.  *10 minutes after finishing my meal I felt hungry*  *After finishing my meal 10 minutes earlier I felt hungry.*  *After I was born, 10 minutes later my mom died.*

Comment: "After finishing my meal 10 minutes earlier I felt hungry " is it me or this sentence means that I finished my meal 10 minutes ago and now I'm hungry?

Comment: That’s what it’s supposed to mean- (which is to say that’s what I took your example sentence to mean as well.)

Comment: In my example sentence I meant: in the past I had a meal, I finished it and after 10 minutes I felt hungry

Comment: I don’t see a difference.

Comment: Sorry I don't mean to annoy you.

Comment: I think I get it now. Earlier refers to the point in the past when I felt hungry,  not to the point when i had a meal.  Big thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also say: after his death 2 years ago she got married. 
The other examples:
1) I agree with Jim. 
2) I was born, and then 10 minutes later my mom died.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] to become more familiar with our standards and operations.

Comment: " After his death 2 years ago she got married". Doesn't this sentence mean that 2 years ago he died and after his death she got married ?

Comment: "" After his death 2 years ago she got married". Doesn't this sentence mean that 2 years ago he died and after his death she got married ? "

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't letting me complete my answer!  I quoted you, then nothing. The answer was: Yes, it does.

Answer (score 0):

"After" is a preposition. "By" is not needed at all. Correct phrasings that include the reference to time are as follows:

"Two years after his death, she got married."

"Ten minutes after I had finished my meal, I felt hungry."

"Ten minutes after I was born, my mom died."